# How to apply gradient to small part of UV Map?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I want to apply a gradient, using the fill tool in texture paint, and apply it to only a small part of my UV map. Any ways I can do that? As you can see, when I apply the gradient, it gets applied  across the whole UV map. Instead I would like it applied to only a small part of the UV map. I could UV map each part separately, but then I wouldn't be able to apply one texture to the whole mesh.

[image]

Thanks,

Best regards,

IdealistDeveloper

Comment: First idea is to use the 3D View painting to do this by using Face Selection Masking to only apply the gradient to the area selected.

Comment: Thank you so much!